# I have an old Macbook A1342 that broke. Is there any way I could repurpose the LCD and give it some sort of video input?

Tags: hardware

My Macbook A1342 broke and before I throw it away I want to try and salvage the screen. I don't have much knowledge of hardware (aside from building PCs, most of my skills exist at the software level) so I have no idea how I would go about doing this. I'm guessing buying some sort of control board to interface between video input and the [serial?] port of the LCD. Anyone know how I would go about doing this, or at least lead me in the right direction?

BTW I don't know of a better stackexchange for this question, so suggestions for that are also appreciated

Answer (score 1):

While possible, it will be pretty difficult. Modern high resolution LCD panels use complicated LVDS interface which requires specialized controller chips and with that screen resolution a standard microcontroller will struggle to push the data to it fast enough. If you nevertheless want to pursue this path, [EE SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com) should give you some hints.